# Matlab, Avoid empty lines

Tags: matlab

I've have a
`function [Q,A] = load_test(filename)` which is loading in a text file. I would like the function to skip empty lines, but i'm not sure how to do it.

I have tried to use

```
~isempty(x), ~ischar(x)
```

but I keep getting an error message. my code so far is:

```
fid = fopen(filename);
data = textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);

Q = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-2), data{1}, 'uni',0);
A = cellfun(@(x) x(end) == 'T' || x(end) == 'F' && ~isempty(x),data{1});
```

what do I need to do ?

Comment: See if this works for you - `data = data{:,:}(~cellfun(@isempty,data{:}),:)`. Not sure what are `Q` and `A` supposed to mean though.

Comment: it does, but in the end I get these error message: Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was char instead.

Error in load_test (line 11)
Q = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-2), data{1}, 'uni',0);

Comment: Try this then `data = {data{:,:}(~cellfun(@isempty,data{:}),:)}`

Comment: it works, thank you. All perfect, Q is a cell Array, containing questions, A is a logical vector containing true or false

Comment: What if I would skip all empty lines and the lines not containing an 'T' or 'F' at the end of the line. Could I somehow change your code ?

Comment: Check out posted answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Your code
fid = fopen(filename);
data = textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter','\n')
fclose(fid);

%%// Additional code
%%// 1. Remove empty lines
c1 = ~cellfun(@isempty,data{:})
t1 = data{:,:}(c1,:)

%%// 2. Select only the lines that have F or T as end characters
lastInLine = regexp(t1,'.$','match','lineanchors') %%// Get the end characters

%%// Get a binary array of rows that have F or T at the end
c2 = strcmp(vertcat(lastInLine{:}),'F') | strcmp(vertcat(lastInLine{:}),'T')

%%// Finally select those rows/lines
data = {t1(c2,:)}
```

Please note that I am not sure if you still need `Q` and `A`.

Comment: thank you. it seems to work perfectly. Could I ask you to say a few words about what happens

Comment: @user2011560 Added few comments to help on that.